# No such file to load -- ftools (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, gcc

Yes, the thing is that I got a really really legacy software, which I need to use it on Ubuntu 10.10 and it requires the use of ruby 1.6.8 and gcc 3.4.

I already install gcc 3.4 and verify the gcc version that I have installed is correct.

```
$gcc -v
```

Then I start installing ruby 1.6.8 by first untar it and do the followings:

```
$./configure
$make
$make install
```

and a error shows

```
./miniruby ./instruby.rb
./instruby.rb:10: in 'require': No such file to load -- ftools (LoadError)
```

I have google many research, and all points to me that ruby 1.9 does not support ftools anymore and I need to change it to fileutils instead....But I am a bit confused because my Ubuntu has even not installed any ruby and what I understand is that the one who "make install" is actually gcc 3.4, not ruby.

Please enlighten me folks.

BTW, FYI, from a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10, this is the command I have run beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libreadline5 libreadline5-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

And then I install gcc 3.4 from the instructions here: http://linux-buddy.blogspot.com/2011/02/install-gcc-34-on-ubuntu-1010.html

Comment: What does the first line of `instruby.rb` say?

Comment: If you type in `ruby` at the shell, you get a message saying ruby isn't installed, right?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm yes, it says ruby is not installed.

Comment: @BenLee `#!./miniruby`  (this is the first line)

Comment: @BenLee I guess you may want to see the whole file, I pasted it here http://pastebin.com/jwgfGGA6

Comment: @chaky, why not just use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` ?

Comment: @BenLee yah, I also has no idea.  It is a damn legacy software by some geek and I didn't want to change it.  But do you want me to try?

Comment: @chaky, yeah I bet that will solve your problem.

Comment: @BenLee you know what, I still got the same error on line 10 of instruby.rb.  I also look deeper into the code, on line 9, it is looking at some lib folder, which I also check that ftools does exists inside this folder.  So wonder why does it say it is missing that ftools file.

Comment: Yah, I just able to overcome the ftools by modifying line 10, and 11 respectively to 

`require "./lib/ftools"`
`require "./lib/find"`

Comment: now I got a newer error on line 22

./instruby.rb:22:in '+': failed to convert nil into String(TypeError)
make: ***[install] Error 1

Comment: somehow, the "make" step, which mkconfig.rb does not populate the rbconfig.rb CONFIG hash for CONFIG['arch'] and some other config variables too